# Atomic store throwing error

Tags: c++, c++11, stdatomic

I recently upgraded to a C++11 compatible compiler, and I was trying to update some code from boost to c++11 standards.  I ran into a problem when converting some code using atomic_store over.  Here is some simple test code that seems to be throwing a compiler error for me.

```
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> m = std::make_shared<int>();
    *m = 1;

    std::shared_ptr<int> a =  std::make_shared<int>();
    *a = 2;

    std::atomic_store(&m,std::move(a));

    std::cout << *m << std::endl;
}
```

the `std::atomic_store(&m,std::move(a));` line is throwing a compiler error for me:

```
'std::shared_ptr<int>' is not derived from 'volatile std::atomic<_ITp>'
     std::atomic_store(&m,std::move(a));
                                      ^
```

Has the way atomic_store changed when moving from boost to C++11?  Do I now need to create an atomic object of a shared pointer?

Comment: Possibly, see e.g. [this `std::atomic_store` reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_store).

Comment: I think this is that rare question that can be entirely answered with but a single word, "yes".

Comment: I also see the following on that site however, which is what confuses me: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/atomic unless I am misreading something, there should be an atomic_store function that takes two shared_ptr's(#4 in that list).

Comment: Which compiler are you using? I think it should compile fine with Clang 3.5. However, GCC 4.9 does not support atomic operations on shared_ptrs, yet.

Comment: I guess that's the problem, I am using GCC 4.8.2, which I thought had support for atomic operations on shared_ptrs.  Thanks for the quick answer, that makes sense.

Comment: libstdc++ status: _"shared_ptr atomic access: partial"_; https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html

Comment: Thank you for the link, I was looking for that site a little earlier actually.  Feel free to leave an answer and I will accept.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following code compiles fine with Clang 3.5:

```
#include <memory>
int main()
{
    std::shared_ptr<int> foo, bar;
    std::atomic_store(&foo, bar);
}
```

However, it doesn't compile with GCC 4.9. The above code prints an error message, that `atomic_store` is not a member of `std`. If I also include `<atomic>`, the compiler prints the error message, that is shown in the question.

Apparently, GCC 4.9 does not support atomic operations for `std::shared_ptr`. See also the documentation of [libstdc++](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html):

> 20.7.2.5 | shared_ptr atomic access | Partial

Answer (score 0):

Currently the only safe and viable way to prevent race condition (when 
smart pointer being copied in one thread is concurrently reset in 
another) is to always use mutexes when accessing these objects, but that 
is more expensive than it needs to be, esp. if multiple readers are 
trying to read the data at roughly the same moment (which is typical in 
publisher/subscriber model).