# alternative to std::atomic_store(shared_ptr) for GCC <= 4.9?

Tags: c++, gcc, shared-ptr, atomic

I tried something similar what's described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24618799/atomic-store-throwing-error) question:

```
// create copy
auto new_data(std::make_shared<some_class>(*this->data));

... // modify *new_data

// apply new data
std::atomic_store(&this->data, new_data);
```

.. and later I realized that on some other machine with gcc 4.8 installed it would not work (like described in the same question).

Is there a workaround - like (temporarily) deriving from `std::shared_ptr` providing the needed interface or just using another atomic operation?

Or do I *have* to provide an external mutex to protect the reading access when I *store* a new object in the global pointer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is of course to just use `boost::shared_ptr` and `boost::atomic_store` instead of STL if Boost is an option. It has the same interface and therefore it's easy to replace.